# How to stop Spark master on windows?

Tags: windows, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

to start master on windows 10 use:
`spark-class  org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master` .
What is the command to close it?

Comment: Probably something like what `spark-daemon stop` does on *nix -- simply kill's the pid (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sbin/spark-daemon.sh#L216)